Does $|a|\neq n$ imply $a^n \neq e$ for an element $a$ in a group $G$?
I’m trying to understand the relationship between the order of an element $a \in G$ and powers of $a$. Specifically, if $|a| \neq n$, does this necessarily imply that $a^n \neq e$?
Here is $e \in G$ the identity element and $|a|:=\operatorname{ord}(a)$ denotes the order of $a$.
Here’s my reasoning so far:

If $|a| = m$, then $a^m = e$ and $a^k \neq e$ for all $0 < k < m$.
If $a^n = e$, then $|a|$ divides $n$, meaning $|a|$ could be smaller than $n$.

However, this makes me wonder: if $|a| \neq n$, does it logically follow that $a^n \neq e?$
I initially thought so, but since $a^n = e$ only requires $|a|$ to divide $n$, I’m unsure if this is always true.
Can someone clarify whether $|a| \neq n$ indeed implies $a^n \neq e$, or if there are counterexamples? How does this reasoning hold up?
Ehat if $|a|=3$ this implies that $a^3=e$
Now $|a|\neq 6$
But example $a^6=(a^3)^2= e^2=e$
Hence $|a|\neq n$ does not imply that $a^n\neq e$
Is this the required counter example?

Please youse MathJax, your post was hardly readable. Questions without MathJax tend do be downvoted and closed. Here is a link for a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Could you explain, why you unaccepted my answer? Is there something wrong with it?

Note that $|a|\ne n\Rightarrow a^n\ne e$ is equivalent to $a^n=e\Rightarrow |a|=n$: and this latter is clearly false.

Your counter example works fine,  and there's zillions of others.

In $G=\Bbb Z_2$ with $e\neq g\in G$,
$$|g|\neq 4\text{ but } g^4=e.$$

Simpler still, in any group, $|e|=1$ but $e^n=e$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$.

Your counterexample is correct. You wrote the proof. The statement is false.
But here another one:
Consider the subgroup of $(\mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}, \cdot): (\{1, -1\},\cdot)$ the identity element $e=1$ and ord$(1)=1\neq 2$ but $1^2 = 1 =e$. Or if you find this counter example rather trivial: ord$(-1)=2\neq 4$ but $(-1)^4= 1$.
In fact its what you wrote: if $a^n=e$ (for example for $n:=$ ord$(a)$)
$$\implies \forall k \in \mathbb N: a^{nk} = (a^n)^k = e^k = e$$

If $a^n=e,$ then $\mid a\mid\mid n.$  It might be fun to try to prove this, using the Euclidean algorithm. Remember $\Bbb Z$ is a Euclidean domain.
Anyway,  we can thus find many, many a counterexample.
